# CGImageAlphaInfo.Last in iOS 8 unsupported parameter combination

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-graphics, ios8

I'm getting an exception as of iOS 8 that was working for iOS 7.  The exception is "Invalid handle" with the message:
: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 524 bytes/row.

Any idea as to why this is no longer a supported parameter?  I've tracked it down to the alpha info "CGImageAlphaInfo.Last" which was used by my PNG Image in the code below where I specified CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = image.AlphaInfo;  Some of my other images that are being used in this function have the "CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst" alpha info which does not cause an exception.  So I'm forcing the alpha info to be PremultipliedFirst for now.

```
            CGImage image = uiimage.CGImage;
            int width = image.Width;
            int height = image.Height;
            CGColorSpace colorSpace = image.ColorSpace;
            int bytesPerRow = image.BytesPerRow;
            int bitmapByteCount = bytesPerRow * height;
            int bitsPerComponent = image.BitsPerComponent;
            CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = image.AlphaInfo;

            // Allocate memory because the BitmapData is unmanaged
            IntPtr BitmapData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bitmapByteCount);

            CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(BitmapData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, alphaInfo);
```

I'm using:

XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

Xamarin Studio 5.4 (build 240)

Comment: A bit more code and the image itself would be helpful to diagnose why this stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

iOS only supports premultiplied alpha.  Use `CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast` instead.

The “Supported Bitmap Formats” section of the [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) does not list any formats using `kCGImageAlphaInfoLast`.
As far as I know, this hasn't changed since iOS 2.0.

Comment: Note that *"iOS only supports premultiplied alpha."* != *"Quartz supports premultiplied alpha only for images."*

Comment: So I can just plug in CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast even though if print out image.AlphaInfo and see that my image's alpha info is CGImageAlphaInfo.Last?  I thought you had to match the alpha info with the image you were reading in just as you would for the Width, Height, BytesPerRow and BitsPerComponent?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.